# OP_RETURN with Multisig

Tags: multi-signature

Let's say I have wallets A,B,C.
A funds multisig address with B and C.
B & C show keys, get input and spent it to OP_RETURN transactions.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you are proposing:

```
Address A: 1Axyz...
Address B: 1Bxyz...
Address C: 1Cxyz...

Tx1

A -> Multisig requiring 1 of 2 signatures from pubkeys of B & C

Tx2

Tx1 output 0 -> OP_RETURN
```

Then yes, that's totally legal on the blockchain. Not sure why you would want to do it, though.

Comment: @IgorBarinov Huh? I think you got cut off there.

Comment: Thanks! So here is the idea: Company B splits an "access key" which can be used to access a file from company’s http server into two parts. One part has been sent to company A using regular communication, e.g. email. We need to prove that both Company A approved to accept this request and client approved to share his file from company B to company A.

Comment: Company A created and funded a wallet to accept this key. Company B and it's client both sign a transaction with part of access key in op_return. Company A knows that the client gave access for this file by signing a transaction and gets second part of the key from the blockchain transaction.